# How to integrate Crossmint payment in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, payment, crossmint

I am getting error while saving.

[image: 1]

I want to save ABI section and proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're attempting to register a testnet contract on goerli in our production system. You should be getting a more meaningful error and I'll look into that now, but if you set this up in our https://staging.crossmint.io/console system you should be good to go!

This is your contract address on goerli testnet
`0x537210CEe33CE059Ab225662e775b54cFEF5C4Ab`

Everything else looks great in your function signature. The main thing our dev console expects to be able to self register a contract is that it accepts an address argument and mints to that instead of `msg.sender`.

Actually, it looks like you started with my [evm-starter](https://github.com/dmulvi/evm-721-starter) contract! Awesome :-)